# Receiver registered but no intent is received in oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

My app will verify the SMS and fetch some data from it. Upto API 26 it was working fine. With Oreo they mentioned implicit broadcast receiver wont work from SO Q&As. I removed my receiver from Manifest and added in run time.

```
 registerReceiver(broadcast, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

SMS permission also given in Run time and i am not sure why there is no intent received. I tried using Service but still same problem.  To get SMS permission am using this code.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
   {

   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(otpreadertwo.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                SMS_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_SUBMIT);
    }
```

Getting overlay permission as well using the below code

```
 Intent intent = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Inside onclick",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
        }
```

my broadcast receiver

```
 public class Bcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
 public  Bcast(){ }
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) { 

     }
    }
```

Also i mentioned the permissions in Manifest. What changes do i need to made in order to receive the intent in Oreo. Please help.

Comment: The `SMS_RECEIVED` action is one of the exceptions to the implicit broadcast restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html. Look at the very end of the list.

Comment: Yes. But it not receiving intent in Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: In which case? The dynamically-registered instance? Or the manifest-registered class? Or do you mean both don't work for you?

Comment: Both didn't work.

Comment: Well, they both definitely work. I've previously tested both API level 26 and 27 emulators, and just re-confirmed on both again. How exactly are you determining that it's not working? That is, what are you doing in the Receiver? Have you added any logs or breakpoints there?

Comment: I toasted a message in onReceive method but no intent is received.

Comment: `Toast`s aren't terribly reliable, and, in fact, I've noticed a slight change in their behavior on the Oreo emulators, anyway. Test with logging or breakpoints. The manifest-registered Receiver should still work, so I'd test that one again first.

Comment: tried with logs but nothing received in onReceive.

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mcve], then. Before that, though, I'd suggest you start a fresh project, and do the minimum three things to get a test SMS Receiver app working, just to make sure you're looking at all the right things. 1.) Modify the manifest to add the `<uses-permission>` and `<receiver>` elements. 2.) Create the `BroadcastReceiver` class with your log, breakpoint, `Toast`, etc. 3.) Install, and manually grant the SMS permission in Settings. This should help you to determine if there is actually an issue with SMS receipt, or if it's something else going on in your project.

Comment: Tried as you said. But its not working with Android emulator running 8.0 and above.

Comment: Well, seems like you've got something fundamentally wrong, then. As mentioned, I've tested multiple times, on both 8.0 and 8.1, using both statically registered classes and dynamically registered instances, and they all work as expected. You ran the app once after installation, yes? How are you sending the SMS? Between emulators, or with the Phone tool?

Comment: I have tested again with new project by clearing all data. It is working fine. I am not sure where the mistake happened. Thanks Mike.

Comment: @MikeM. Is this receiver also work if application has been killed from background? actually I am also having same issue but its working fine application doesn't kill from recent stack. Please help me for the same

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi "Is this receiver also work if application has been killed from background?" – No, not like is shown in the question. This shows a dynamically-registered Receiver instance, so it will stop working whenever the `Context` it's registered on is destroyed. I'm not sure exactly what your issue is, but perhaps you just need to register your Receiver class in the manifest instead?

Comment: Yes I Register it in manifest but when i killed the application from recent I stop receiving the broadcast.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Then it sounds like you have some issue with a particular device-specific behavior. Simply removing an app from Recents, by itself, should not affect manifest-registered Receivers. I seen many reports, however, of non-standard systems that do stop those, for whatever reason. If there is no user setting available to modify that behavior – e.g., something about running, or specifically receiving SMS, in the background – either in the device Settings, or in some other security/administrator-type app, then I can't really help ya. I've never used any devices with such restrictions.

Comment: this issue coming in oreo one plus 6

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Yeah, sorry, I can't help you. I've never used that brand/model. That is one of those that I seem to recall reports of similar problems with. About all I can suggest is to check for any system setting that might be related. You might also try including that specific brand/model in your searches on this issue.

Comment: So manifest register broadcast will work in oreo also ?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Yes, on standard systems, it will work. Quoting myself from the first comment here, "The `SMS_RECEIVED` action is one of the exceptions to the implicit broadcast restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html. Look at the very end of the list."

Comment: Ok . Thanks for your valuable support and time

Comment: I also face the same issue in oreo. So does your snippet work on all oreo phones?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi any solution ?

Comment: @Erum this is device specific issue. There is no solution for that

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi yes this is device specific but i m getting same problem in Oreo Emulator too .... is there any solution ?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi any solution this is not device specific issue , as receiver is registered in manifest and explicit receiver but not getting fired in Oreo

Comment: @Erum you have to register receiver dynamically  means at runtime.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi i cant register receiver as i have to broadcast receiver from SyncAdapter class extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter 
this reciever will start from background how can handle that in Oreo
i also tried to start service  ... but its not working

Comment: pls join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow